# What is the role of the server in a WebRTC chat room?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

With WebRTC, do you still need the server to act as a route-to-peer mapping layer? As in you create a chat room that works via WebRTC. This chatroom has a generated link. That link gets sent to someone else who wants to connect. The server is still responsible to pooling peers in the "room" but is then absent from the data transmission steps to come after that.

Correct? Trying to figure out where that cut off is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're partially correct. To exchange streams via `RTCPeerConnection`, you need to first use a **signaling channel** to exchange some `SessionDescription` secrets.

[image]

This is usually done via `Websockets`. The server knows all `peers` of a given `session`, and also gives a shared communication channel to all peers.

HTML5Rocks has a [nice article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/) explaining WebRTC and signaling channels.

But you don't need to use a **central server**.
You can ditch your server and use a `Distributed Hash Table` as a peer tracker, and [direct webrtc](https://github.com/feross/webtorrent/issues/288) as your signaling channel. Highly experimental material.

Comment: so how they handle the communication between different members of the room and how Data be transferred between different parties fro example if user A send video stream , will it be sent three times if I have 3 other users in the room